# C - separating number from the string

Tags: c, string, return

I wrote a simple program which is returning value after a space: for example input"alababa 4" gives return 4, in there is no spaces then it's 0. But now I want to scanf that string, and it just doesn't work, I have no idea where am I making mistake.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(){

//char * string="alababa 4" - it worked that way
char * string;

scanf("%c", &string);
int dlugosc=strlen(string);

  for(int i=0;i<=dlugosc-1; i++)
  {

  char temp;
  temp=string[i];
  char str2[] = " ";
  if(temp==' ')
  {

      char * pZnak = strpbrk( string, str2 );
      printf( "%s \n", pZnak ); 
      return pZnak[1]-48;  

  }

  }
  return 0;
}
```

Second question, why return is 48 bigger than it should be?

Comment: `scanf("%c", &string);` -> `scanf("%[ ^\n]%n", &string, &length);` and of course, you need to allocate space for   `string` previously. Oh and the length of the string will automagically be stored in `length` with the `%n` modifier, read about format specifiers for `scanf()`, all of it and it will amaze you!

Comment: neat trick, never used `%n` before +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created a pointer to char, but not allocated memory for it. The simplest way is to create a char array with some fixed size.
   In `scanf` `%c` means read a single character, to read a string use `%s`, but `scanf()` reads only to space symbol, not to '\n'. When you type "alababa 4" it will read only alababa. You can use `gets()` or `fgets()` to read the whole string. Also the variable `string` is already a pointer you dont need to use `&` there. The right syntax would be: `scanf("%s", string);` but as I said it will read only first word.
   The `pZnak[0]` in your program holds 'space' and the `pZnak[1]` holds '4'. The ASCII code for '4' is 52.
   Here is the program that reads the string from keyboard and prints everything after space symbol on screen.

```
#include <stdio.h>  // for printf() and gets()
#include <string.h> // for strpbrk()

int main(void) {
    char string[80]; // It can contain a string of 79 symbols + '/0'
    char *checkStr = " ";
    gets(string);
    char *ptr = strpbrk(string, checkStr);
    printf("%s\n", ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the problem is quite different. First of all you passed an address of a pointer variable which is not pointing to some valid memory location where the `scanf` can store the inputted data. You have invoked undefined behavior in your code.

The thing you want can be done using `sscanf` which basically uses `scanf` on a buffer. `sscanf(buf,"%s%d",str,&num)`. But here in case it fails it will not return the value `2`. But this solution is not that good - `scanf` class is good for formatted input (lots of hassle involed with error checking wit `scanf`). A better would be to parse the input string using `strtok`. If you got one tken then it's done. There is no digit or number provided. If it's return 2 token then use `strtol` to get the second token's integral value.

In case you know that there will be only 1 digit then you can do a simple looping - and check the second token you found in earlier paragraph. If you get a digit and it is the only one then you can be sure that that is the only digit that you have to parse. You can simply store it in an `int` variable.

Illustration code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXLEN 100
int main(){
    char s[MAXLEN+1];
    int numParsed = 0;
    int iter = 1;
    if(fgets(s,MAXLEN+1,stdin)!=NULL){
        char * str= strtok(s," ");

        while(str!=NULL){
            str = strtok(NULL," ");
            if(iter && str!=NULL){
                iter = 0;

                char *t;
                errno = 0;
                long n = strtol(str, &t, 10);
                if ((errno == ERANGE && (n == LONG_MAX || n == LONG_MIN))|| (errno != 0 && n == 0)) {
                    perror("strtol");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                if (t == str) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "No digits were found\n");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                if ( n >= INT_MIN && n <= INT_MAX)
                {
                    numParsed = n;
                }
                else{
                   fprintf(stderr, "Too big/small a number\n");
                   exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
                }
            }else if(iter == 0 && str){
                fprintf(stderr, "%s\n","Input=> String[SPACE]Num" );
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

        }
        if(iter == 0)
            printf("[%d]\n",numParsed );
        else
            printf("%s\n", "Format: String[SPACE]int");
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`scanf("%c",...)` reads in a single character, not a 0-termianted sequence of characters. Hence, `char * string;scanf("%c", &string);` is wrong in two ways: (1) it reads in a character into a pointer to a pointer to a character, and (2) it does not read a string as intended but a single character. And if you write `char*string;scanf("%s",string)`, then you read in a string into invalid memory (since pointer `string` does not point to validly allocated memory), which is undefined behaviour.

You'd have to write `char string[20]; scanf("%19s",string)`.
Then you can parse the input string as desired. BTW: your parser seems to be a little bit complicated; a simple `if (scanf("%*s%d",&num)==1) { ...` would do the job; the `*` indicates that the input for `%s` shall be parsed but not stored somewhere, and the `%d` reads the numeric part after having skipped all white spaces in between.

Comment: In the question, OP has mentioned - _there is no spaces then it's 0_.  `scanf("%*s%d",&num)` doesn't fit in this requirement.